# fetchall() not working even with values in database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am working in python with sqlite3 and I am trying to create a database.

I created a table:

`c.execute("CREATE TABLE persoane (nume text, varsta integer, salariu integer)")`

Then I added the values into the table:

`c.execute("INSERT INTO persoane VALUES('David', 16, 1000)")`

When I try to get the values out of the database with `fetchall()` I get an empty list `[]`

I know the values had been added because I verified it with an online program.

This is the full code for reference:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('baza_date.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE persoane (nume text, varsta integer, salariu integer)")

conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO persoane VALUES('David', 16, 1000)")

conn.commit()

print(c.fetchall())
```

Comment: You need to execute a query to retrieve the data, for example `SELECT * FROM persoane`.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you should always mention the target columns for your insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute a query and then use the `fetchall()`. For example:

```
info = c.execute("SELECT * FROM persoane;").fetchall()
print(info)
```

Otherwise, you're not selecting anything from your database, and your `c` cursor doesn't know what you want to fetch.